# DOM element doesnt load when using ng-view attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm new in angularjs , I using angularjs framework for my first web app and all the thing work fine , But I want to add some charts that works with jquery , I have an Index.html file that contain   for loading another html file in index.html file when clicked on a menu, but when I click on the menu chart doesn't show because DOM element doesn't load and it take few secend to load , for example when i call the highchart function in 2secend later it works fine and draw chart because DOM element load successfully , how can i solve this problem? without using setTimeout ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try wrapping your event in the jQuery .ready method, which specifies a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

or

```
$(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

Comment: !! it depend to click event !!